# What kind of cable can be used to power a mobile electric machine running of 6 kV AC?

Tags: cables, high-voltage, insulation

I'm looking into the specifications of Hitachi hydraulic excavator model EX8000E-6 with electric motor. The spec says the motors are of type HITACHI TFOA-KK and run off *AC 6 000 - 6 600 V / 50 Hz*, each of the two motors is rated at 124 amperes. In the picture (left bottom corner) there's a cable:

[image: cable]

The cable looks as if it was a domestic vacuum cleaner cable - simply laying around.

Crafting such a cable looks like a major challenge - it has to be flexible and have enough insulation to withstand the 6 kilovolts in the wires. All the high voltage cable I've seen so far were designed for being buried underground and so were not really flexible. Even they have [untrivial design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/16877/3552).

How are such flexible cables for voltages around 6 kilovolts designed that they feature flexibility and capability to insulate the high voltage?

Comment: Although the cable looks tiny it has a 1850mm track width and just taking a rough look at the image looks like the cable is probably somewhere around 100mm diameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

6kV is not actually so big deal.

Every cable production company (at least the bigger one) has such cables in their catalog.

Note, that such cables has multi layered insulation and probably the upper layer is made from abrasion resistant rubber. There are internal layers that provides the actual insulation.

A middle grounded braid layer provides the safety.

[Here is an example with data sheets, found by simple search on my local cable distributor's site.](http://www.filkab.com/main/bg/products/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%8A%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8/%D0%93%D1%8A%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_/%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8/_%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%9D/NTSCGEWOU/110/)

Comment: Do you have any specific example of a cable that looks suitable for such application?

Comment: @sharptooth - in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

EDITED - don't bother trying to say it has a diesel engine like I did because it comes in two versions.
This version has an engine: -

[image]

And presumably it cannot be powered from a trailing cable.

If it helps save my reputation, I've worked down coal mines with really powerful electric machinery operating at 3,300V 50Hz and these were +1MW machines that ran up and down a "longwall" coal face shearing coal off onto a conveyor belt. The cables, from memory were about 4 inches diameter and as tough as old boots.

The trouble with the Hitachi is that if it over-extends itself it's going to unplug itself from the static generator and it's going to be a real b**ch to plug it back in!

Comment: That's the wrong model, there is a EX8000E-6 that has electric drive as per the question: http://www.hitachi-c-m.com/global/pdf/products/excavator/large/ex8000e-6/KS-EN124.pdf

Comment: Yeap, this thing comes in two flavors - one runs on diesel you quote and another one has 6 kV AC motors instead.

Comment: @PeterJ I wonder what happens when it drives off too far and unplugs itself - not going to be easy to plug it back in without an engine for reversing back towards the power point.

Comment: @Andyaka - there is an automation invented to check for such events as overtightened cable and to stop the machinery. And do you thing such machines are just plugged in a big plug on the wall?

Comment: @johnfound of course not - I was trying to be amusing

Comment: @Andyaka - Ah, it is clear now. It is because of my missing sense of humor (especially in English). :) +1

Comment: @Andyaka: Regarding "what happens when the machine drives too far and unplugs itself" - the trailing cable is often used in 100m lengths with sockets and plugs on each end. When you reach the end of your cable, you plug in another 100m length of cable "extension".

Answer (score 2):

You would want a "trailing cable" such as those used by the mining industry.

In Australia, Olex is a manufacturer of such cables. See the [Olex mining catalogue](http://www.olex.com.au/Australasia/2012/OLC12641_MiningCat_FA.pdf).

Special features of such cables include:

- The conductor is more finely stranded, to allow better flexibility.
- The insulation is a synthetic rubber like EPR, which is flexible, instead of the usual XLPE or PVC, which aren't as flexible.
- Construction features to resist crushing and abrasion
- **IMPORTANT** - a pilot wire used to monitor the circuit. You attach a pilot wire monitoring relay to the pilot wire, which sends a small loop current out to the end of the cable and back. If the cable is cut, the loop current is interrupted, and the pilot wire monitor disconnects the power. This is an important safety feature to prevent live HV conductors being exposed in case the cable is cut.

Here is a chart from the Olex catalogue, showing the features of their range of trailing cables for the mining industry. The range covers voltages from 1kV to 33kV.

[image]